# How to start or configure the gitlab pages on linux

Tags: gitlab

Could please anybody suggest me to enable the GitLab-Pages in linux. I started the gitlab-runner with 'http://domian-name.com/' and token provided by the shared runner manually. I job was successed but pages were not deployed.Even i didn't find the repository's page settings. I changed /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb and set: pages_external_url 'http://domian-name.com/'. Still i failed to enable the gitlab pages in community edition

[image]

Comment: Do you own the domain "domian-name.com"?

Comment: yes,Here i am taking my domain-name.it is mapped with an ip address

Comment: Is it neccessary to add a wildcard DNS A record pointing to the host that GitLab runs ? we already mapped  ip with domain-name.

Comment: Is this question is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744566/how-to-run-the-gitlab-pages-deamon-in-linux)?

Comment: I was unable to start the gitlab pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goto the /etc/gitlab folder. open the gilab.rb file

[image]

uncomment the above two lines

Reconfigure GitLab using the command : gitlab-ctl reconfigure. Next,

Restart nginx and gitlab-pages:
gitlab-ctl restart nginx,
gitlab-ctl restart gitlab-pages